# Is there a program that will allow me to tag photos within XP, much like I can in Windows Vista/7 in explorer?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, images, windows-explorer, tags

Much like how one can tag JPG images in windows explorer from within Vista or Windows 7, is there an application or shell extension that would allow me tag these photos the same way from within XP? Thanks.

Comment: never tried it but looks promising..http://lunarfrog.com/

Comment: I use Google's [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/). It allows some tagging and is pretty good software all around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try **[Google Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/)**. It has a good interface also.

Comment: this has already been posted as a comment. -1

Comment: it should be the comment that's removed then, not this - we want answers, not comments.

Comment: Does this work with the windows tagging system? I usually tag my photos in explorer, but want to make sure that I can tag them the same way (i.e., be able to update a photo in picasa and those tags will work within Vista/7's explorer).

Comment: It does not add to the windows tagging system unfortunately.